# Why do sql queries with two conditions take a long time?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 12 million records. There are indexes on columns col_1 and col_2. I use postgresql 9.3. 
I need two types of queries on it. First, some queries with just one condition in where clause, such as:

```
select count(*) 
from table_1
where 
   col_1 >= 123456;
```

**explain analyze:**
@CraigRinger

```
Aggregate  (cost=164523.60..164523.61 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1803.281..1803.281 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Index Only Scan using table1_col1_idx on table_1  (cost=0.43..151242.20 rows=5312558 width=0) (actual time=60.713..1344.393 rows=5318333 loops=1)
     Index Cond: (col_1 >= 123456)
     Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 1803.330 ms
```

and one other query like:

```
select count(*) 
from table_1
where
    col_2 >= 987654;
```

**explain analyze:**

```
Aggregate  (cost=364134.66..364134.67 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=3935.708..3935.708 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Index Only Scan using table1_col2_idx on table_1  (cost=0.43..334739.38 rows=11758111 width=0) (actual time=7.521..2904.569 rows=11760285 loops=1)
     Index Cond: (col_2 >= 987654)
     Heap Fetches: 0
Total runtime: 3935.760 ms
```

But, the problem is huge run time of a combined where clause: when two or more conditions combines with AND/OR. For example:

```
select count(*)
from table_1
where
    col_1 >= 123456; AND col_2 >= 987654;
```

**explain analyze:**

```
 ->  Seq Scan on table_1  (cost=0.00..650822.93 rows=5295377 width=0) (actual time=0.056..45445.711 rows=5301622 loops=1)
     Filter: ((col_2 >= 987654) AND (col_1 >= 123456))
     Rows Removed by Filter: 6494640
Total runtime: 45961.622 ms
```

It's unacceptable: 3 seconds against 45 seconds! So, is there any solution to improve such combined queries? How to modify this query to force planner use indexes on col_1 and col_2?

I also, tried :
set enable_seqscan = false;

Then,  the planner modifies its search plan to bitmap scan; that results in run time = 137 seconds!!!

```
Aggregate  (cost=666246.28..666246.29 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=137311.964..137311.964 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_1  (cost=99440.46..653007.83 rows=5295377 width=0) (actual time=1105.153..136527.723 rows=5301622 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: (col_1 >= 123456)
     Filter: (col_2 >= 987654)
     Rows Removed by Filter: 16711
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..98116.62 rows=5312558 width=0) (actual time=862.677..862.677 rows=5318333 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (col_1 >= 123456)
Total runtime: 137314.450 ms
```

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: Assuming there are indexes on col_1 and col_2, it's probably doing an index-only scan for the individual queries, but must look up the table for the others, or if the data window is too large (likely) just do a full table scan for the combined one

Comment: Please see he "asking better questions" section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info then *edit your question* appropriately.

Comment: @Bohemian Probably a bitmap index scan, but we shouldn't have to guess - this question should include `explain analyze` output and the PostgreSQL version. Still, +1 anyway for actually including the queries...

Comment: Did you try a combined index on `(col_1, col_2)`?

Comment: I shouldn't create combined indexes, because the rate of insertion and updates on table_1 is so high. So, defining combined index on (col_1, col_2) will lead to low performance of insert and update commands.

Comment: If you define an index on `(col_1, col_2)` you can remove the index on `(col_1)`, so you still have only two indexes that need maintenance during inserts and updates. The new index will certainly be bigger than the old single-column one, but I don't think it will impact the performance as much as you think: besides you need to decide which performance is more important: insert or select speed.

Comment: In fact, the table has 10 columns col_1 ... col_10, and I need all single-column indexes on these columns. So, I can't remove any indexes. The select speed is more important, as it is used in a UI. But, the high rate of inserts in the table is the matter I can't avoid, that will affect insert speed dramatically.

Comment: You only posted `explain`, not `explain analyze`. Please use `analyze`. A plain `explain` doesn't show if the statistics are accurate, what the selectivity is, etc. (You can at-reply me when done if you want to notify me of the edit).